Is this SQL clause meaningless?
I ran across something strange in the SQLite "SqlLogicTest" test suite:
WHERE (e>c OR e<d)
   AND d>e

The e<d and d>e parts are exactly equivalent to one another, so this could be rewritten as WHERE (e>c OR d>e) AND d>e.  And since the right half of that OR clause is now guaranteed to be true for any row that passes the filter, you can further logically simplify it as WHERE (e>c OR true) AND d>e, and then to WHERE true and d>e and then simply to WHERE d>e, cutting out the OR subclause entirely.
Granted, this is just a test suite, so I don't expect it to be representative of actual real-world code, but it makes me wonder.  Is there any reason someone would write a query like that?  Am I missing something in my logic, or is the OR subclause entirely redundant and meaningless here?

(e > c OR d > e) AND d > e is not equivalent to the (e > c OR e < d) AND d > e; (e > c OR d>= e) AND d > e is (yielding the same result, assuming reflexivity). If c IS NULL this boils down to e >= d AND d < e, which means the query must not have a result regardless of what e and d are.

@user2722968 Where are you getting a >= from?

Take a look at the query plan (which you get witth EXPLAIN or something similar; yuo didn't tell us which make and version of table server you use). It will very likely tell you if it was able to reduce your condition.

tested with online compilers, comparison like e>d gives null if any of them is null, now NULL OR <condition> will return TRUE(1) if condition is true, if not,it will return NULL instead of FALSE(0), NULL AND <condition> will return FALSE(0) if condition is false, if not,it will return NULL instead of TRUE(1), so NULL OR e<d is not NULL (my bad) nor is it e<d

You (the OP) are absolutely correct in that the first part is redundant and the where clause can be logically simplified to WHERE d>e. For <anything> AND d>e to be true, d and e must be non-NULL with d greater than e. If this is true, then (e>c OR e<d) will also be true regardless of c's value (even if it is NULL) as the or e<d part will also always be true.
